# Python best practice: try except pass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Small question, one for me to just learn best practice more than anything. If there is a better way to do this please critique :)

Basically I have multiple GPIO inputs that correspond to one button press. So for example, if the user presses button 2, I get High values from pin 5, and pin 6.

So in my code, I need to map the High pins to a "button" id.

To do this, I am using a 2D list where the index of the elements will correspond to the "id" of the button.

```
buttons = [
    [],
    [PIN_5],
    [PIN_5, PIN_6],
    [PIN_6],
    [PIN_6, PIN_19],
    ...
]
```

I am using a threaded loop to check for pin values, and storing the high state pins in a new list.

So once a button is pressed, a new list will have what pins are high.

```
pins_high = [PIN_5, PIN_6]
```

So this is where my best practice question comes in, to map those pins to the button "id" in the mapping list, I am using a **try except pass** approach

```
button_pressed = 0
try:
    button_pressed = buttons.index(pins_high)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Is this best practice? It seems to me like a nice neat solution, but am I overlooking any possible leaks/effects of using a try/except/pass like this?

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: if inside except then catch error and print or log the error. Why you want to pass statement.  https://github.com/aviboy2006/flask-rest-api/blob/master/app.py see this as reference.

Comment: You should probably use a dict instead

Comment: Thanks. I want to pass because I don't need anything to happen if the ValueError exception is raised by the .index() function. According to the documentation it raises this exception if it doesn't find the values you "search" for. So I'm using it here to say, "get me the index of my pins if they exist, if not, do nothing"

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks, I'll read into the differences and see how I can adjust.

Comment: @aviboy2006: When you're catching a targeted exception and the exception indicates an expected state of affairs, not an error, there is no reason to print or log it, any more than you are required to print/log in an `else:` attached to an `if`. `except: pass` (or the slightly less bad `except Exception: pass`) is a no-no, and `except ValueError: pass` would be a problem if the `try` block was large and could raise `ValueError` in many different ways, but this use case is fine.

Comment: I can show an example but need to see a short example of what you actually do with `button_pressed` afterwards for context

Comment: @Tomerikoo It then gets put into a JSON object and sent to an API. I just literally need an Integer / Number to send with it to say what button was pressed.

Comment: So `0` for example will be a valid option for unknown button?

Comment: You should use python dictionaries. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp   Use exceptions only when you really have to and only for exception handling.

Comment: Thanks @Gabor, looking into it :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yeah, 0 would be ignored by the API but otherwise still a valid number to send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) is first of all more efficient (look-up time of `O(1)` as opposed to the `list.index`'s `O(n)`), and also reduces the need for `try/except` with the help of the [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method. The *"problem"* is that dicts' keys need to be hashable - which lists are not. So you will need to convert them to tuples (which are hashable):

```py
buttons = {
    (PIN_5,): 1,
    (PIN_5, PIN_6): 2,
    (PIN_6,): 3,
    (PIN_6, PIN_19): 4
}
```

And now using the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method you check for a key, and if it is not found, it will return the second `default` argument:

```
button_pressed = buttons.get(tuple(pins_high), 0)
```

---

Note that this is *"order-sensitive"* - meaning that `[PIN_6, PIN_5]` will return `0` and not `2`!

Answer (score 1):

no.
First thigns first: whenever you have to retrieve a value given a key, just use a dictionary:

```
buttons = {
    (): 0, 
    (PIN_5,): 1,
    (PIN_5, PIN_6): 2, 
    ...
}
```

See that (1) the values can be arbitrary, and no need to do hacks so that the rder of insertion of your combination needs to match the numeric value you need, and (2),  search order is arbitrary, O[1], no linear search for each button press, and (3) dictionaries have the `.get` method that allow you to check for containment without needing to handle exceptions.

Moreover, and a bit more "advanced" - you can use "frozenset" objects for the keys, so you don't depend on button order:

```
F = frozenset

buttons = {
    F(): 0, 
    F((PIN_5,)): 1,
    F((PIN_5, PIN_6)): 2, 
    ...
}  

...

button_pressed = buttons.get(F(pins_high), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help and explanation :)